# Broken SVG Filter id link when using History API with Ember CLI

Tags: ember.js, svg, ember-cli, html5-history, svg-filters

I'm generating SVG visualizations with D3.js in an Ember-cli Application.
The SVGs utilize filters and markers that are accessed through the id attribute:

```
<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="filterId">
            ...
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <g>
        <g class="nodes">
            <circle filter="url(#filterId)" ...></circle>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

This works fine on the index page (url: ), but is broken when traversing to other routes (ex: \otherRoute). It will work on the other route if I change circle to

```
<circle filter="url(./otherRoute#filterId)" ...></circle>
```

But it then breaks on the index and all other pages.

I can fix it by manually prepending the url to #filterId when building the svg elements on each route or by using the hash locationType in ember-cli (which uses /#routeUrl instead of /routeUrl), but was wondering if there was a generic way to automatically link to the current url so I can still use the history API?

Comment: Put the filter in a standalone SVG file and give it an absolute URL perhaps?

Comment: This is a very important issue for me. I am rendering an amCharts chart in a nested component, and due to this issue, my charts look pretty weird sometimes. After I switched to hash urls the problem is gone. The problem is I do not have much control over HOW amCharts generate the svg elements. Any tips on how to adjust amCharts to play well with nested components in Ember.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ran into the same issue with a clip-path attribute after moving from hash URLs to the history API. The original implementation was an SVG element like:

```
<svg>
  <clipPath id="clip-path-ember1919">
    <path d="..."></path>
  </clipPath>
  <g clip-path="url(#clip-path-ember1919)">
    <rect ...></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

This had been achieved with a simple D3 append:

```
var emberId = this.$().attr('id');
svg.append('g')
    .attr('clip-path', "url(#clip-path-#{emberId})");
```

To solve the issues raised by the history API, I used the same solution you described (prepending the URL), but by using `window.location.pathname`:

```
var emberId = this.$().attr('id');
var relPath = 
svg.append('g')
      .attr('clip-path', "url(." + window.location.pathname + "#clip-path-" + emberId + ")");
```

This creates an SVG element much like the circle element referenced in the question.

```
<svg>
  <clipPath id="clip-path-ember1919">
    <path d="..."></path>
  </clipPath>
  <g clip-path="url(./path/to/page#clip-path-ember1919)">
    <rect ...></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Long way of saying: similar solution to the original poster, just using `window.location.pathname` to generate the prepended URL.